# QEMU Headless display issues after updating collabvm

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, qemu

[image]

This is an issue I have been countering after I updated qemu on my server running collabvm and it happens when I change the resolution up and down anyway I have zero idea why it happens.

Yes I have tried on desktop but I get same issue, the only version that I have verified to be working is qemu 4.2